# About DIVs (Hiding and Showing not Java)

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="abc" style="display: none;"><h1>abc</h1></div>
```

Hello! I hide the div but I want to see when I type it **#abc**  I can't see this text.

Comment: When you type #abc where? To show a div that is in display:none you need javascript. You can't show up a div after "something" happens with just css and html.

Comment: Adress bar. In chrome. End of the adress.

Comment: So you are trying to make the div visible by adding its id to the url? In that case, look up `:target`

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to do this. Example : example.com#abc

Comment: You can do it using javascript. I really don't know right now how to achieve what you want using just html / css. In js you can retreive the #abc from url and then show up the div with the abc id.

Comment: Like [that](https://abcdefgh.carrd.co/#abc).

Comment: I'll write you an answer with some code.

Comment: I'm waiting for code. Thanks.

Comment: Posted. Please accept it if it's doing the trick :)

Comment: Oh, I thought you didn't want to use JavaScript, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below sample as per your requirement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {

if(window.location.href.indexOf("#abc")!=-1)
{
    //alert("Page is loaded");
    document.getElementById("abc").style.display="block";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h1>Hello World!</h1>


<div id="abc" style="display: none;"><h1>abc</h1></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case people want to do it without having to resort to JavaScript, the CSS solution is to use the `:target` pseudo class, as mentioned in the comments.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <style>
   #abc {display:none}
   #abc:target {display:block}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="abc"><h1>abc</h1></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it using jquery:

```js
var url = "https://abcdefgh.carrd.co/#abc";
var hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#"));
// You can use 
// var hash = window.location.hash; 
// but i need to write the url to show you that is working.

if ($( hash ).length) { //check if div exists
 
    $( hash ).show();
 
}
```

```css
#abc, #cde
{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">ABC</div>
<div id="cde">CDE</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#abc")!=-1) {
    document.getElementById("abc").style.display="block";
}}
```